# LoginView Rolegroups not working on same one

Tags: asp.net

So I have the User, Admin and Dev role, yet I can't see the area for Admin and Dev?..

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lgMenu" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="User">
            <ContentTemplate>
                             // Content               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin, Dev">
            <ContentTemplate>
                            // Content               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Logistica">
            <ContentTemplate>
                          // Content
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
     </RoleGroups>
 </asp:LoginView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview?view=netframework-4.7.2

> Role-group templates are searched in the order they are defined in the source. The first matching role-group template is displayed to the user. If a user is a member of more than one role, the first role-group template that matches any of the user's roles is used. If more than one template is associated with a single role, only the first defined template is used.

You only match your first group. Move it up, like this, if you want that to take precedence.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lgMenu" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin, Dev">
            <ContentTemplate>
                            // Content               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="User">
            <ContentTemplate>
                             // Content               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Logistica">
            <ContentTemplate>
                          // Content
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
     </RoleGroups>
 </asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: I see, so it's either a new login view or just copy the same html when user has multiple roles